# PHP Open a file and give it parameters/variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, fopen

With this code I create new files with information from a database:

```
function getLocations() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `plaats` FROM `plaatsen` ORDER BY `plaats` ");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $city = $row['plaats'];

        $handle = fopen( "cities/$city.php",'w');

        echo "<a href='cities/".$row['plaats'].".php' class='col-md-4'>"."<div class='steden'>".$row['plaats']."</div>"."</a>";

        fwrite($handle, '<?php include("../stad.php") ?>');
        fwrite($handle, $city);
    }
}
```

The output are multiple links and files with different cities like: Amsterdam, Rotterdam, Den Haag. Now the content on these pages has to be different depending on the city it is. So basically the page should know which city it is and dan download content for this city from a database.

I tried to do this with writing a var to the pages which does write the city name to the page, but I cannot (as far as I know) do anything with this information.

Does someone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: you want to pass   `$city` value  to other page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$handle = fopen( "cities/$city.php",'w');` - ERK! This is really bad for security. Allowing your webserver uid write access to files which will then be processed by PHP is not in itself a vulnerability but provides a vector for escalation of an attack.

There may be a good reason why you want to cache content outside of your database - but use a caching reverse proxy or ESI or (as a last resort) implement caching of HTML fragments in your PHP code **DO NOT USE PHP CODE AS A CACHE**.

As to the question of identifying the name of a file PHP code is running in - PHP can get this from the `__FILE__` constant. e.g.

```
<?php

print "I am in " . strtok(basename(__FILE__), '.');
```

To determine the filenames involved in a hierarchy of includes, have a look at debug_backtrace()

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about that. I solved it with a $_GET function :  

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `plaats` FROM `plaatsen` ORDER BY `plaats` ");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $city = $row['plaats'];
        echo "<a href='gebruikers.php?city=$row[plaats]' class='col-md-4'>"."<div class='steden'>".$row['plaats']."</div>"."</a>";
    }

And at the other page: 
    $stad = $_GET['city'];
    echo $stad;